# HackerRank Python - some test cases get "Terminated due to timeout", how can i optimize the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently, on HackerRank, I am trying to solve the [Circular Array Rotation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) problem. Most of the test cases work, but some are "Terminated due to timeout".

How can I change my code to optimise it?

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys


n,k,q = input().strip().split(' ')
n,k,q = [int(n),int(k),int(q)]
a = [int(a_temp) for a_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]

m = []
for a0 in range(q):
    m.append(int(input().strip()))

for i in range (0, k % n):
    temp = a[n-1]    # Stores the last element temporarily
    a.pop(n-1)       # Removes the last element
    a = [temp] + a   # Appends the temporary element to the start (prepends)


for i in range (0, q):
    print(a[m[i]])
```

Comment: This probably is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to transform the list at all. Just subtract `k` from the index you're passed whenever you do a lookup (perhaps with a modulus if `k` could be larger than `n`). This is `O(1)` per lookup, or `O(q)` overall.

Even if you wanted to transform the actual list, there's no need to do it one element at a time (which will require `k` operations that each take `O(n)` time, so `O(n*k)` total). You can simply concatenate `a[-k:]` and `a[:-k]` (again, perhaps with a modulus to fix the `k > n` case), taking `O(n)` time just once.